# Font-size Responsivo

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo

estou precisando de uma ajuda para ajustar um detalhe no site do cliente, pois estou gerando alguns cards na tela quando cadastrado, mas conforme a a resolução da tela ele não fica bem, então, venho até aqui pra pedir a ajuda de vocês pra tornar o font-size do texto que há dentro do meu card

**Parte do sistema que gera os cards com um retorno de array**

```
<div id="scroll" style="height: 90px; top:0px;" ng-select ng-model="selection" select-class="{'chips_style_altered': $optSelected}">
            <div  ng-repeat="frete in fretes" class="pad col-md-1">
                <div name="{{frete.frete_id}}" ng-select-option="frete" ng-click="carregarBairros(frete.frete_valor, cidade.cid_atd_id,selection)" class="col-md-12 padding-zero chips md-whiteframe-1dp" >
                    <div class="text-center" >
                        <span class="font-text">R$ {{frete.frete_valor}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fonte não responde ao redimensionamento nos navegadores, ela responde ao zoom in/zoom out e configurações dos navegadores, para que você possa deixar sua fonte responsiva nos navegadores você deve definir o tamanho dela conforme a resolução, você pode fazer assim:

### Exemplo:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

   body { font-size: 2em; }

}
```

Lembrando que este exemplo diminui toda fonte do site de acordo com o máximo da sua largura. você pode definir apenas o card para receber uma fonte menor.

Você pode também utilizar  [calc() - Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc):

```css
body {
  font-size: calc(0.75em + 1vmin);
}
```

```html
<h1>I'm an H1 Heading</h1>

<p>Everything, it said, was against the travellers, every obstacle imposed alike by man and by nature. A miraculous agreement of the times of departure and arrival, which was impossible, was absolutely necessary to his success. He might, perhaps, reckon
  on the arrival of trains at the designated hours, in Europe, where the distances were relatively moderate; but when he calculated upon crossing India in three days, and the United States in seven, could he rely beyond misgiving upon accomplishing his
  task? There were accidents to machinery, the liability of trains to run off the line, collisions, bad weather, the blocking up by snow&mdash;were not all these against Phileas Fogg? Would he not find himself, when travelling by steamer in winter, at
  the mercy of the winds and fogs? /p>
```

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, me ajudou, bom trabalho, grato, sucesso!